# Web Security, baidu.com

Tags: security, http, port

I run a node.js http server and I have noticed that baidu.com logged on to my site accessing it with my IP cause I dont have any domain linked to it. As well as google. Now I can understand that google came to crawl my site since I type my IP several times a day in google chrome adresse bar. And google have been looking for site index and robot files. However, baidu.com did not request any of that but instead requested there own domain name to my server. And ever since Baidu visited me, I cant connect to my port 80.  If I type in my adresse as usual I can see for a fraction of second in the console log the following;

```
err_unsafe_port    my.ip.add.ress:1
```

I can see this message only if I refresh like crazy cause it stays on very shortly.

This append just after baidu.com came to visit me.

So there is only 2 solutions I can think of.

1. I have been attacked and some changes where made.
2. My ISP blocked my port 80 after noticing trafic to my ip.

But what does the port 1 have to do with it?